# Insert into binary tree without sorting input

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

how can you build binary tree without sorting it, I.E

if i have a input 5 4 9 8 1 2 7 how can you insert that into a reference based binary tree. 
I know this can be easily implemented with Array, but is it possible with reference base?

Comment: Nope its just some extra work that we can do to sharpen our skills

Answer (score 3):

```
Tree buildTree(int[] array, int index) {
   if(index > array.length) { return null; }
   return new Tree(
     array[index],
     buildTree(array, 2 * index + 1),
     buildTree(array, 2 * index + 2));
}
```

Most of the work is in the recursion and in the indexing, but it's not too bad at all.

Answer (score 2):

One simple rule is to always insert into the left subtree and then switch the subtrees.  The right subtree will always be 0-1 elements larger than the left subtree, so you can always insert into the left subtree.  Now, the left subtree is 0-1 elements larger than the right subtree, so you want to switch the subtrees to preserve the invariant.  In pseudocode:

```
insert(t,v) {
    if (t == null) {
        return new TreeNode(v,null,null)
    } else {
        left = insert(t.left,v)
        right = t.right
        t.left = right
        t.right = left
        return t
    }
}
```

Comment: This builds a sorted tree, something the OP explicitly asked not to do.

Comment: I read that as build a tree (that I assumed was sorted) from unsorted input.  Fixed.

Comment: @Retief- Your answer is still pretty vague about how specifically to accomplish this, and I don't think it can be built into a working answer without significant effort.  If you can improve your answer to detail exactly how you'd build the tree, then I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: @templatetypedef Better?  I am omitting iterating across the list, inserting each one into the tree so far, but that is not a complex or hard to write function.